# ngx-bootstrap carousel pause on hover being lost when clicking next/prev buttons

Tags: angular, carousel, ngx-bootstrap

I have an angular5 app with a page implementing the ngx-bootstrap carousel component using the default [noPause] property to pause the scrolling through images actions, which is working fine.

When I click through the slides using the next or previous button controls the slide's auto scroll starts up again so the carousel skips through two images at a time with each click, so the fact the mouse is over the carousel is ignored.

The demo version of the carousel seems to have a similar issue (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel#pause-on-hover) but i'm not sure if it's possible to re-set the noPause value when clicking through slide? Not sure if anyone would know if this is possible?

This is my implementation of the carousel:

```
<carousel [noPause]="false">
  <slide *ngFor="let item of carouselItems">
    <img [src]="item.mediaFileURL | safeUrl" />
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the carousel code will trigger the play() of the carousel on the (mouseup) event, fired when clicking the next/prev buttons. So I was able to add a wrapper  around the carousel to overwrite the event and run the carousel's pause() function instead.

```
<div (mouseenter)="setPause()" (mouseleave)="setPlay()" (mouseup)="setPause()">
```

I was able to run the functions on the carousel by adding a reference to the competent in my typescript file using:

```
@ViewChild('carousel') carousel: CarouselComponent;

setPlay(): void {
    this.carousel.play();
}
setPause(): void {
    this.carousel.noPause = false;
    this.carousel.pause();
}
```

Hopefully that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

try activeSlideChange listen to slider event and set noPause to false

```
<carousel (activeSlideChange)="noPause = false" [noPause]="false">
```

Comment: Hey Fateh, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to fix the issue. The carousel still gets set back to auto play (loop) when the arrow is clicked and the slide changes.